# What is equivalent technology available in java to do MSMQ operations

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I am having a requirement to send messages from server to client.

In .Net side the **MSMQ** technique is used to achieve these mechanism.such as sending messages,notifications and etc.

Please let me know the effective technology to use in java side.

Comment: i would say jms for application queuing needs. ActiveMQ etc for bigger integration needs.

Answer (score 0):

Quite similar to MSMQ is RabbitMQ and works quite well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Apache MQ or even JMS.